# How to apply slide animation between activities

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

hey friends i have problem in applying slide animation between activities. I have applied slide animation between activities so it work on emulator and next activity will open with slide animation but when i run same code in mobile then it doesn't work.

**my left slide animation**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:shareInterpolator="false">
        <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
          android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
         android:duration="700"/>
       </set>
```

**my right side animation**

```
  <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:shareInterpolator="false">
          <translate
           android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
           android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
           android:duration="700" />
        </set>
```

I m totally confused because when animation work on emulator so why not in mobile. so please suggest me the solution of this problem and helpers must be appreciated.

Comment: which device you are testing on?

Comment: samsung galaxy-y device i m using

Comment: are you sure you running the same apk on device which you ran in emulator?

Comment: yes i m 100% sure the same apk run on mobile .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same problem. This answer solved my problem [How Do I Make a Swipe Animation From Left To Right Transition Between Activities In Monodroid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212610/how-do-i-make-a-swipe-animation-from-left-to-right-transition-between-activities/13224118#13224118). The animations need to be turned on by going to Settings->Display->Animations and selecting and saving All Animations.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested the clean option of Project menu in Eclipse?

Comment: hey i have test on other mobile then my animation work but on my mobile it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the previous APK from device and try, it should work.

Also take into consideration comments of @MKJParekh and @breceivemail.

If that still doesn't helps you out try running on some other device and test the results. Also make sure you are using layouts dimensions as for your device screen you are testing on.