# How Do I Make a Swipe Animation From Left To Right Transition Between Activities In Monodroid?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-animation

I'm developing using Monodroid and want to be able to swipe left or right and load new activities as I do so. I also want to have an animation that shows the next activity slide into the screen while the other slides out.

I've tried OverridePendingTransition using XML resource files as well as implementing animations. None of this is working for me, however. Has anyone had success with this? Could you place your code here and not a link to some blog or website?

Putting this in OnCreate in all my activities does not work:

```
this.OverridePendingTransition(Resource.Animation.slide_in_right, Resource.Animation.slide_out_left);
```

XML code:

Slide in right:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shareInterpolator="false" >
<translate
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

Slide out left:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shareInterpolator="false" >
<translate
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

I haven't found any simple code to detect the gesture of swiping left or right. Ideally I'd like to be able to have two functions:

```
OnSwipeLeft()

OnSwipeRight()
```

And then I'd hope the code is a simple for animation (of course I Know I need to hook into more with these functions:

```
AnimateSlideLeft();

AnimateSlideRight();
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears animations were not enabled on my phone and that I had to go to the settings on my Android phone and enable animations. Once I did this, the animations worked. To do this, click on the Android settings button (in the lower left for my phone). Tap the "Settings" Box. Then tap "Display". Then tap "Animation". Then tap "All animations". Once I did this, everything worked.